# How do I convert `serde_json::Value` into a list or a Vec<_>?

Tags: json, rust

So I can read a json file with `serde_json`:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

use serde_json::Value;
use crate::scene_builder::SceneBuilder;

fn json_hello_world() {
    // Some JSON input data as a &str. Maybe this comes from the user.
    let data = r#"
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "age": 43,
            "phones": [
                "+44 1234567",
                "+44 2345678"
            ]
        }"#;

    // Parse the string of data into serde_json::Value.
    let value: Value = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
    let phones = &value["phones"];
    println!("phone[0]: {}", phones[0]);
    //println!("number of phones: {}", phones.size());
    // compilation error: method (.size()) not found in `Value`
}

fn main() {
    json_hello_world();
}
```

and print out value of a list element with correct index: `println!("phone[0]: {}", phones[0]);`

But how do I convert such a `serde_json::Value` into a list or `Vec<Value>` so I can access its size/length, like `let phones: Vec<Value> = value["phones"];` or `let size = phones.size();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`as_array()`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/enum.Value.html#method.as_array):

```rust
println!("number of phones: {}", phones.as_array().unwrap().len());
```

But the right thing to do is to deserialize into a typed struct:

```rust
#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
struct Data {
    name: String,
    age: u32,
    phones: Vec<String>,
}

let value: Data = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
let phones = &value.phones;
println!("phone[0]: {}", phones[0]);
println!("number of phones: {}", phones.len());
```

Answer (score 0):

```rust
let phones = value["phones"].as_array();

    if let Some(phones) = phones {
        println!("phone[0]: {}", phones[0]);

        let size = phones.len();
        println!("number of phones: {}", size);
    } else {
        println!("Invalid JSON structure: 'phones' is not an array.");
    }
```

The `as_array` method returns an `Option` because the value may not be an array. In case the value is not an array, the method will return `None`, and you can handle that condition accordingly.